# application plugin - how to add application argument to start script?

Tags: gradle

My application needs a program argument and I would like to bundle my distribution with the program argument pre-set.

Currently I'm using this:

```
startScripts{
 doLast{
  unixScript.text = unixScript.text.replace(
    'exec "$JAVACMD" "${JVM_OPTS[@]}" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed "$@"', 
    'exec "$JAVACMD" "${JVM_OPTS[@]}" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed "$@" /app/etc/connect-jdbc.properties')
  }
}
```

Is there an option with the application plugin to help me do this?

Comment: What is the problem? Isn't it working correctly?

Comment: It also seems that this might be what you're looking for: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.jvm.application.tasks.CreateStartScripts.html